# How do I add a value to a nested hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a nested hash:

```
hash = {
  "a" => "a",
  "b" => {
    "c" => "c",
    "d" => {
      "e" => "e"
    }
  }
}
```

and I have a hash:

```
new_value = {
  "b.d.e" => "new value"
}
```

I need some sort of "magical" function that replaces the value of the hash at `hash["b"]["d"]["e"]`, like:

```
magical_function(hash, new_value)
#=> hash = {
      "a" => "a",
      "b" => {
        "c" => "c",
        "d" => {
          "e" => "new value"
        }
      }
    }
```

I have no idea how. Can someone help please?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried to solve this one recursively, but I failed :S I think it might be the only way to solve it..

Comment: has to be an update (destructive) or can it be a merge?

Comment: It's important to include a small example of the code you've written with your question. Without it we'll think you haven't done your homework, haven't tried, and likely will close the question as not being valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
class Hash
  def replace_value(*keys, value)
    current = self
    current = current[keys.shift] while keys.size > 1
    current[keys.last] = value
  end
end
```

Called by invoking `hash.replace_value("b","d","e", "new_value")`.

Comment: Wow! I like your solution! Short and nice + it works like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

It's not magical if it's implemented in a straight-forward manner:

```
merge_hash.each do |key, value|
  parts = key.split('.')
  leaf = parts.pop

  target = parts.inject(hash) do |h, k|
    h[k] ||= { }
  end

  target[leaf] = value
end
```